# Replicate lines containing specific words

Tags: notepad++

I want to edit a file using Notepad++, in such a way that I can copy(replicate) a line containing a specific word with some minor changes --

Example --
if the file has --

```
lASER_BALL
COMET_BALL
...
```

I want to change it to

```
LASER_BALL
LASER_BALL_END
COMET_BALL
COMET_BALL_END
...
```

Im talking about a file with a huge number of entries. Any idead on how this can be done using Notepad++ ?

Comment: voting to close - you could easily use Copy/Paste?

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> for search and replace:

[image]

Then, Select All <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a regex find and replace

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace (Ctrl-H)
2. Select "Regular expression" in "Search Mode"
3. **Find what: `(.*)`

   Replace with: `\1\r\n\1_END`**
4. Replace All (with In selection not ticked)